# C++ struct member is a reference to class

Tags: c++, struct, reference

can a struct member be a reference to another class?
I have this struct in header file:

```
struct stop_object {
    timetable& tt;
    std::string stop_name;
    std::set<std::string> platforms;
};
```

and this class in header file:

```
using stop_container = std::vector<stop_object>;

class timetable {
    public:
    stop_container timetable_stops;
    platform_container timetable_platforms;
    platform_route_container timetable_platform_routes;
    route_departure_container timetable_route_departures;
    trip_container timetable_trips;
    trip_departure_container timetable_trip_departures;
};
```

I can not build the program. It says: missing type specifier. for timetable& tt;
How can I achieve that I will have the reference to the parent object in which the struct is?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, classes can store references.  Please post a [mre] to get help with your error.  Do note that having a reference member makes your class no longer copy/move assignable.

Comment: Isnt there problem with cycle referencing? From class timetable to struct stop_object and so on...

Comment: See the duplicate link for *Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes* on how to fix the circular dependency.

Comment: @Rikib161999 Yes there is.  You can fix that by putting `struct timetable;` before `class timetable { ...`.

Comment: @PaulSanders there cant be struct and class with the same name

Comment: Soryy, I meant put `class timetable;` before `struct stop_object`.  Apologies for the error.

Comment: Then I get error: the default constructor cannot be referenced
when I want to initialize my struct

Comment: In adfdition to not being copy/move assignable, your class is also not default-constructible. Write a constructor that initializes it reference member.